# Warum wird „furchtbar“ als Verstärker genutzt?

Tags: etymology, adjective

Häufig werden Adjektive durch bestimmte Wörter nochmal bekräftigt, z. B. »Er ist stinksauer.« oder »Er ist stinkreich.« Seltsam aufgefallen ist mir aber ein anderer Verstärker: *Furchtbar* hat eigentlich eine eher negative Bedeutung und wird trotzdem mit positiven Adjektiven verbunden:

> Ich bin furchtbar glücklich.
>
> Ich bin furchtbar entspannt.
>
> Das ist furchtbar nett.

Woher kommt also dieser Gebrauch von *furchtbar*?

Comment: *Stinken*, wie in *stinkreich* hat auch eine eher negative Bedeutung.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, aber _sauer_ und _reich_ meint in diesem Fall auch nichts Positives. Ferner erscheint mir eine Verbindung von _stinken_ und _glücklich_ eher schwierig.

Comment: Dass *reich* nichts positives bedeutet wäre aber das Neueste. Man kann auch ein Schweineglück haben und scheißfreundlich sein, analoger Fall.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn man jemanden als *stinkreich* oder *scheißfreundlich* bezeichnet, möchte man den Reichtum bzw. die Freundlichkeit wohl in der Tat nicht positiv hervorheben, auch wenn diese Eigenschaften *normalerweise* positiv besetzt sind.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Gut, bei "scheißfreundlich" klingt mit, dass es eine aufgesetzte Freundlichkeit ist, eine geheuchelte. Beim Reichtum ist das aber nicht der Fall. Stinkreich kann man jmd. bezeichnen, den man aufrichtig beneidet und dem man großen Respekt entgegenbringt.

Comment: @userunknown Die Diskussion um "reich" führt zwar von der eigentlichen Frage weg, ist aber schon interessant. Aus Sicht des Reichen ist Reichsein  natürlich positiv, aus Sicht der Besitzlosen sind Reiche meist unbeliebt.  "Reicher Sack" ist sicher kein Ausdruck der Bewunderung.  Vgl. auch die politische Diskussion um die *Reichensteuer*.

Comment: User unknown: Non olet - Geld stinkt nicht. Du brauchst einen Riesenhaufen Geld damit es riecht. Also stinkreich sein (keine Ahnung ob es daher kommt, aber es hört sich gut an).

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Welche Belege hast Du dafür, dass Reiche aus Sicht der Besitzlosen meist unbeliebt sind? Bei "reicher Sack" drückt das "Sack" die abfällige Meinung aus und stand hier nicht zur Diskussion. Was soll die pol. Diskussion um die Steuer belegen? Dass Reiche unbeliebt sind? Das nimmt hier eine naive Tendenz auf! Wer "stinkreich" sagt, der muss überhaupt keine Bewertung zum Ausdruck bringen wollen, sondern drückt einen Tatbestand kraftvoll aus. Man kann auch Neid und Respekt gegenüber jmd. hegen, der einem unbeliebt ist. Das sind alles unterschiedliche Fragestellungen.

Comment: @userunknown Mein letzter Kommentar war unsachlich. Ich habe ihn gelöscht. In Zukunft werde ich mich bemühen, nur noch Kommentare zu Fragen und Antworten abzugeben - und nicht mehr zu Kommentaren Dritter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es ist eine normale Entwicklung, dass negativ besetzte Wörter gewissermassen als Kraftaftausdruck zur Verstärkung verwendet werden, und zwar auch im positiven Sinn. Am Anfang mag ein schockierender Effekt mitspielen, wie ihn die Jugendsprache sucht, aber mit der Zeit können solche Wörter Eingang in die allgemeine Sprache finden und dermassen verblassen, dass die ursprüngliche Bedeutung vergessen geht. Ein paar Beispiele:

- “f**king awesome”
- «huereguet» – wörtlich ‘Huren-gut’, in der Schweiz geläufig
- «schandbar gut» – (altmodisches) Verstärkungswort in der Schweiz, mittlerweile derart verblasst, dass man keinen Zusammenhang zum Wort «Schande» mehr erkennt und es als völlig harmloses «[schampar](https://idiotikon.ch/wortgeschichten1/123-rueuedig-schampar)» auffasst
- «sehr gut» – die ursprüngliche Bedeutung ‘wund, krank’ ist völlig verblasst, ausser in Wörtern wie «versehrt» oder in englisch “sore”.

Siehe auch:

- [Huere • Wortgeschichten • idiotikon.ch](https://www.idiotikon.ch/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=331&Itemid=225)

Comment: Interessant, die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von _sehr_ war mir auch nicht bekannt. Aber wie hat sich _furchtbar_ eigentlich durchgesetzt und nicht z. B. _grauenhaft_?

Comment: @Devon: Über Details des Sprachwandels kann man nur philosophieren.

Comment: @Devon. - Fragen mit "warum" in Bezug auf Sprachen sind sowieso immer Fragen, die ins Philosophieren münden.

Comment: Ein Vorschlag steht in meinem Antwort.

Answer (score 8):

It's literally the same as "terribly" in English. Even though it's rooted in the word "terrible", it's often used in the sense of "VERY".

Comment: Also works with "ужасно" in Russian!

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, Grimm & Grimm & al., Deutsches Wörterbuch, s.v. „furchtbar, adv.“ (fascicule published in 1869) does not have one single quotation for "furchtbar" in the meaning “sehr”; all of the quotations imply actual “fear” of one sort or another. On the other hand, the CNRTL site has citations for “terriblement” in the sense « extrêmement » as far back as 1375. One might take this as suggesting that the German usage of “furchtbar” as a mere intensifying adverb is a fairly recent calque on French.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/furchtbar#furchtbar

https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/terriblement